# what's wrong with my Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I want to implement a method that find all the files in a folder and its sub folders and so on...
I have implemented it by recursion but i don't know what is wrong.
can someone help me?

```
private void fileLister(){
    File d = new File(adress);
    File[] existingFiles =d.listFiles();
    for(int i = 0;i<existingFiles.length;i++){

        if(existingFiles[i].isDirectory()){

            fileLister();

        }
        else{

            List<File> templist = Arrays.asList(existingFiles);
                allExsistingFiles.addAll(templist);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `adress` will always be the same ...

Comment: Pass in `File d` as a parameter to the method. Also, you don't want to keep on adding all of `existingFiles` to the array each time you find a non-directory element. Just `allExsistingFiles.add(existingFiles[i])` would suffice.

Comment: It's a simple change to get it to work the way you planned - I added an answer below with a minimal change to your code. If you think it's worthwhile, could you accept it by clicking on the check mark next to the answer, making it green? Up-vote is also nice :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need each call to the recursive method to have the directory you are working in that call. The minimal change should be:

```
    private void fileLister(File directory){
    File[] existingFiles =directory.listFiles();
    for(int i = 0;i<existingFiles.length;i++){

        if(existingFiles[i].isDirectory()){

            fileLister(existinFiles[i]);

        }
        else{

            List<File> templist = Arrays.asList(existingFiles);
                allExsistingFiles.addAll(templist);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check IT:

```
public void showAll(String directoryName, ArrayList<File> files) {
    File dir = new File(directoryName);

    File[] fL = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : fL) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            files.add(file);
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listf(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
        }
    }
}
```